# Illustrator: Why are color options grayed out and why do does pressing "D" changes my doted lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

[image: As you can see paths is gray, and options are grayed out]

[image: After pressing "D" options are selectable and drawing is trully black, but the dotted lines and stroke weight configurations are gone]

As you can see paths is gray, and options are grayed out.
After pressing "D" options are selectable and drawing is trully black, but the dotted lines and stroke weight configurations are gone

Any ideas how to change my drawing from gray to true black without affecting anything else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if you are working with the stroke, why don't you make that your primary (X key)?
The option is probably grey because your current primary (fill) is empty . 
Pressing D is choosing the default colors (white fill/black stroke), and it also resets your stroke, so that action makes no sense in your case.
You should select your entire artwork, double-click your stroke and enter the value you want in the Color Picker.
Also, it looks like your first example is transparent  - why is that ?

[image]

Hope it helps you 
Have fun!

Comment: Yea I figured that about the D hotkey, thanks anyways.The first exmaples is not transparent, it just gray, dont know why, even when I choose black

Comment: I see. Well, I've edited my answer, so that you can see what I'm referring to. The stroke does indeed look transparent.
And it would certainly  explain why your stroke won't chance to black from grey, right?
I hope that you'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a step you are missing here. You still need to **select the stroke indicator in the color palette** in order to change the stroke color properties.

Skip hitting D. Just click on the stroke indicator to bring it into focus, then you can make it whatever color you want while retaining your dashed properties.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can select one stroke and then go to Select > Select Same > Select Same Color (or one of the other options that will work best for you). And then change the stroke color to whatever you want. You may have to repeat a couple times, but this makes faster work of selecting all the individual lines.

[image]